# Apache POI autosizing a percent formatted cell

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm having some issues with autosizing cells. After my program populates and formats each accordingly, it autosizes the cells to make it look visually acceptable. The issue is, when the cell is formatted as percentage, it auto-sizes the cell without taking in consideration the fact that there's a '%' character, so we end up getting #### on the cells until you expand the cell. Is there a way to autosize it WHILE taking in consideration that extra '%' character?

EDIT:

[image]

So this is what happens, the left VAR has been autosized correctly for whatever reasons, but the VAR on the right hasn't.

EDIT2:

I noticed that this ONLY happens when the cell value is 0.00% So all the values in the column for VAR that has #### were 0s and some of the values in the left column for VAR were non-zeros.

Answer (score 1):

While this may not be an ideal solution, one possibility is to grab the size of the string you are inserting into the cell (ie. "50.00%" = size of 6), and set the cell width based manually based on that.

Comment: I too, have considered this solution, but it seems wrong that I would have to go around and do it this way. If apache poi doesn't provide the means to do it however, then this seems to be my only choice :(

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid this is not supported in Apache POI, as it disregards the custom cell formatting when trying to calculate column width (it only takes font characteristics and rotation into consideration, but no DataFormat).

As a workaround you can try to write your custom autoSizeColumn method as a modification of the one currently implemented, i.e.:

```
   public void autoSizeColumn(Sheet sheet, int column, int plusMinusChars) {
        double width = SheetUtil.getColumnWidth(sheet, column, false);

        if (width != -1) {
            width += plusMinusChars;
            width *= 256;
            int maxColumnWidth = 255*256; // The maximum column width for an individual cell is 255 characters
            if (width > maxColumnWidth) {
                width = maxColumnWidth;
            }
            sheet.setColumnWidth(column, (int)(width));
        }

    }
```

Then you can call it with an extra '%' character to be printed out:

```
//4th column autosized + 1 character in width to accomodate for '%'
autoSizeColumn(sheet, 3, 1);
```

Comment: Apache POI *does* try to take account of formatting applied to a cell when autosizing, see [around line 154 of SheetUtil](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/java/org/apache/poi/ss/util/SheetUtil.java)

Comment: That's only partially correct, while the the `getCellWidth` function users the formatter correctly, `getColumnWidth` function forces it to be a default (blank) one (see the line 203). I believe this decision has been made based on the fact that `DataFormat` can be defined either by cell's data format, default row data format or columns data format, which would make the whole decision process of applied format fairly complex.

Comment: A `DataFormatter` object still looks up the format strings based on the `Workbook` that the cell belongs to, so your mis-interpreting line 203. There could still be a bug, mind you, but it *ought* to work... If you have a test case that shows the problem, please report it to [the Apache POI project!](http://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/buglist.cgi?product=POI)

Comment: I will provide a screenshot tomorrow when I have the test case @Gagravarr

Comment: I've just tried with 3.10, and a `0.00%` formatted column of 0 values was auto-sized correctly. Can you see how your case differs from the [stackoverflow23114397 unit test](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/testcases/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/TestBugs.java)?